# iOS App Authentication with Windows Azure AD

Tags: ios, windows, azure, ios7, active-directory

Is this possible to authentice iOS Mobile App with Windows Azure Active Directory(AD) with utilizing mobile web services of Azure.

Basically iOS App should be login with only the Windows Azure Active Directory(AD)

I found one third party library 
https://github.com/MSOpenTech/azure-activedirectory-library-for-ios/
but not sure whether this is secured or should be used or not

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Open Technologies (MSOpenTech on Github) is Micrsoft's official approach to helping open source communities both on and off the Microsoft platform.  This should give you confidence in the legitimacy  of the code on Github.  See here for more details: https://msopentech.com/